# Get Today's date in Java at midnight time

Tags: java, date

I need to create two date objects. If the current date and time is March 9th 2012 11:30 AM then

> - date object d1 should be **9th March 2012 12:00 AM**
> - date object d2 should contain the current date itself

The date will not be entered, it is system date.

**Update**:

```
Date dt = new Date();
System.out.print(dt.toString());
```

gives current date and time

Comment: What has been tried? Did it work? If not, why not?

Comment: @pst the added section is the d2 that I want. Now I need d1 object that is midnight time.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
    Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); //anything 0 - 23
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    Date d1 = c.getTime(); //the midnight, that's the first second of the day.
```

should be Fri Mar 09 00:00:00 IST 2012

Comment: Shouldn't you also have to set the milliseconds to zero?

Comment: Also set the timezone -  
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
cal.setTimeZone(tz);

Answer (score 31):

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

Comment: please modify your code as `System.out.println(sdf.format(date));` then it is better..

Comment: This is not at midnight as the question asks.

Answer (score 26):

Here is a Java 8 based solution, using the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)). 
**If you can use Java 8 objects in your code**, use [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html):

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now(); // current date and time
LocalDateTime midnight = now.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay();
```

**If you require legacy dates, i.e. [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html):**

Convert the `LocalDateTime` you created above to `Date` using these conversions:

> [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) -> [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) -> [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) -> [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

1. Call [`atZone(zone)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#atZone-java.time.ZoneId-) with a specified time-zone (or [`ZoneId.systemDefault()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#systemDefault--) for the system default time-zone) to create a `ZonedDateTime` object, adjusted for [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) as needed.

   ```
   ZonedDateTime zdt = midnight.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Montreal"));
   ```
2. Call [`toInstant()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#toInstant--) to convert the `ZonedDateTime` to an `Instant`:

   ```
   Instant i = zdt.toInstant()
   ```
3. Finally, call [`Date.from(instant)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#from-java.time.Instant-) to convert the `Instant` to a `Date`:

   ```
   Date d1 = Date.from(i)
   ```

**In summary** it will look similar to this for you:

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now(); // current date and time
LocalDateTime midnight = now.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay();
Date d1 = Date.from(midnight.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
Date d2 = Date.from(now.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

**See also** section [Legacy Date-Time Code (The Java™ Tutorials)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/legacy.html) for interoperability of the new `java.time` functionality with legacy `java.util` classes.

Answer (score 10):

```
Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance(); //Get the current date
SimpleDateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MMM/dd HH:mm:ss"); //format it as per your requirement
String dateNow = formatter.format(currentDate.getTime());
System.out.println("Now the date is :=>  " + dateNow);
```

Comment: This is not at midnight as the question asks.

Answer (score 4):

If you are able to add external libs to your project. I would recommend that you try out Joda-time. It has a very clever way of working with dates.

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Comment: +1 for suggesting Joda. its DateMidnight class should do it for you.

Comment: @AshwiniRaman No, not `DateMidnight` any longer. All the "midnight"-related classes and methods in Joda-Time have been deprecated. They were based on faulty ideas. Instead use the [`withTimeAtStartOfDay`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay--) method on `DateTime`.

Answer (score 3):

Using org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils

```
Date pDate = new Date();
DateUtils.truncate(pDate, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution in **Java 8**:

```
Date startOfToday = Date.from(ZonedDateTime.now().with(LocalTime.MIN).toInstant());
```

Comment: Using Java 8 is great. Two suggestions: (1) Give explicit time zone. (2) Use `LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Karachi")).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Asia/Karachi"))` to take the case into account where the day doesn’t begin at 00:00 (typically at transition to summer time (DST)). Alternatively use `ZonedDateTime.truncatedTo()`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Java 8 way to get UTC Midnight in millis

```
ZonedDateTime utcTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
long todayMidnight = utcTime.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC) * 1000;
```

Comment: Or shorter: `LocalDate.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ).atStartOfDay( ZoneOffset.UTC )`

Answer (score 1):

```
private static Date truncateTime(Calendar cal) {
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        return new Date(cal.getTime().getTime());
}
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Date d2 = new Date();
        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.setTime(d2);
        Date d1 = truncateTime( cal );
        System.out.println(d1.toString());
        System.out.println(d2.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Current Date and Time :

```
String mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

This will shown as :

Feb 5, 2013 12:40:24PM

Comment: This is not at midnight as the question asks.

Answer (score 0):

## Defining ‘Midnight’

The word “midnight” is tricky to define.

Some think of it as the moment *before* a new day starts. Trying to represent that in software as tricky as the last moment of the day can always be subdivided as a smaller fraction of a second.

I suggest a better way of thinking about this is to get “first moment of the day”.

This supports the commonly used approach of defining  a span of time as ‘Half-Open’, where the beginning is inclusive while the ending is exclusive. So a full day starts with the first moment of the day and runs up to, but not including, the first moment of the *following* day. A full day would like this (notice the date going from the 3rd to the 4th):

> 2016-02-03T00:00:00.0-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]/2016-02-04T00:00:00.0-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]

## Joda-Time

If using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) library, call [`withTimeAtStartOfDay`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html%23withTimeAtStartOfDay--).

Note how we specify the time zone. If omitted, the JVM’s current default time zone is implicitly applied. Better to be explicit.

```
DateTime todayStart = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) ).withTimeAtStartOfDay() ;
```

If using Java 8 or later, better to use the java.time package built into Java. See [sibling Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31683549/642706) by Jens Hoffman.

Answer (score -1):

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");    
Date date = new Date(); System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));    //2014/08/06 15:59:4
```

Comment: This is not at midnight as the question asks.