# sql.Timestamp 1 second error when converting from Calendar

Tags: java, mysql, calendar

**SCENARIO**

I'm modifying an app, and have a shitty database which I cannot modify. In one of the cases I duplicate an entity I need to put today's date without time.

- In the `MySQL` DataBase, field is a `DateTime`.
- In the `Java` entity, field is a `Timestamp`

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629636/get-todays-date-in-java) this will be enough to get today's date at midnight:

```
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

Then I just need to add it to my entity, as the `Java` field is a `Timestamp` I use [Calendar::getTimeInMillis](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) method:

```
mEntity.setDate(new Timestamp(c.getTimeInMillis()));
```

i also tried:

```
mEntity.setrDate(new Timestamp(c.getTime().getTime()));
```

**PROBLEM**

In my database I always get one more second:

```
2015-04-08 00:00:01
```

That causes bad sorting by Date in the querys. I'm sure I can easily find a workaround, but I don't want to mess more the code and I cannot see why is this happening. **Maybe I'm doing something wrong? Or is this the normal behaviour?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try resetting the millisecond :

```
c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

Comment: **This is a workaround, not an answer to my question**... If this is needed why [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629636/get-todays-date-in-java/9629822#9629822) has so many votes?

Comment: you retrieve time in milliseconds but if you don't set it to zero with millisecond precision, then it won't be zero (it's `00:00:00:NNN`, NNN being random), and perhaps because of "rounding", seconds is 1 not zero