# Date to Calendar - Performance

Tags: java, performance, date, calendar

Most of the methods e.g. `getYear()`  `getMonth()` are depricated and mentions to use `Calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)` instead.

However, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185966/converting-a-date-object-to-a-calendar-object), in order to do that, we would need to write:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
```

Also, `Calendar.getInstance()` does not return same instance of Calendar, but returns a new instance always.

Is there a faster way to get Year, Month, Day, etc from Date, instead of creating Calendar instance and setting date and then getting the required information?

In other words, is there any more performant way to achieve so?

Comment: You're worrying too much for new instance creation. With current JVM, the cost of creating an object like `Calendar` is negiglible.

Comment: Use the Java 8 Time API or JodaTime...

Comment: FYI, in high volume on an Intel MacBook, (a) `Instant.now()` (replaces `java.util.Date`) takes ≈ 65 nanoseconds, (b) `ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId )` (replaces `Calendar`) takes ≈ 255 nanoseconds, and (c) `LocalDate` (replaces `java.sql.Date`) takes ≈ 210 nanos. Not likely a bottleneck in your app.

Answer (score 0):

GregorianCalendar or SimpleDateFormat, but I guess if you want more uses and want to be more specific you can use http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

source: [Get Today's date in Java at midnight time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629636/get-todays-date-in-java)